# Mongoose nextObject

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying out mongoose for the first time. I can't seem to find something equivalent to mongodb cursor nextObject. this code:

```
    Question.find().sort({date:-1}).nextObject().exec callback
```

results in

```
TypeError: Object #<Query> has no method 'nextObject'
```

and I can't seem to find anything about this using google or in the pretty terrible mongoose documentation.

Comment: Can I ask why you need access to the `nextObject()` function?  Are you just trying to find one document which matches your query?

Comment: In this case I'm looking for the top result, latest or oldest question in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the newest or oldest, could you not use `findOne` paired with `sort`?

```
// finds the question with the most recent date
Question.findOne().sort({date: -1}).exec(function(err, question) {
    // ...
});

// finds the question with the oldest date
Question.findOne().sort({date: 1}).exec(function(err, question) {
    // ...
});
```